# How can you filter a reactive data table with a checkbox in R shiny without breaking the "spread" function?

Tags: r, shiny

I am experimenting with the development of an interactive dashboard in R shiny. I pull data from relational databases using SQL into my workspace. The data looks similar to this:

[image]

and can be loaded with the following code

```
df<-data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c", "b", "d", "a", "b"),
               Event = c("AF-11", "AM-12", "AM-15", "AF-20", "AF-21", "AM-17", "AM-50", "AF-30", "AM-19", "AF-45", "AF-46", "AM-22", "AM-29", "AM-33"))
```

In the app, I want to produce a data table from the above data that has been rearranged to look like this:
[image]

The following code gets us there:

```
d1<-df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  add_column(variable = "Thing") %>%
  mutate(times = 1:n(),
         tot_times = max(times)) %>%
  unite(both, variable, times) %>%
  spread(both, Event) %>%
  arrange(desc(tot_times))
```

This code works just fine in Shiny. However, I want to add a mechanism that allows the user to toggle between event types using a checkbox. In order to do this, I pull the "AF" and the "AM
out of the string using gsub in a "mutate" function and use a "filter" function to choose between the event types in the app based on what the user has checked in the checkbox. The app is below:

UI

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Stuffs")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("The Thing", tabName = "thething", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem( tabName = "thething",
                 h4("The Thing"),
                 fluidRow(box(width = 12, dataTableOutput("table1")),
                          box(width = 5, checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Thing Type", choices = c("AM", "AF"), selected = "CF", inline = TRUE))))
        
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df<-reactive({d1<-data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c", "b", "d", "a", "b"),
                   Event = c("AF-11", "AM-12", "AM-15", "AF-20", "AF-21", "AM-17", "AM-50", "AF-30", "AM-19", "AF-45", "AF-46", "AM-22", "AM-29", "AM-33"))
    })
    
    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
        
        d1<-df() %>%
            mutate(EventTypes = gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", Event)) %>%
            filter(EventTypes %in% input$checkbox) %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            add_column(variable = "Thing") %>%
            mutate(times = 1:n(),
                   tot_times = max(times)) %>%
            unite(both, variable, times) %>%
            spread(both, Event) %>%
            arrange(desc(tot_times))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The checkbox correctly sorts between the two types depending on what is toggled, but it breaks the spread command and I no longer get one participant per row. Instead, each participant has a row for each event type.

[image]

Obviously the way I am going about this is incorrect, but I don't understand the code well enough to figure out the proper way to do this. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In all situations, you want a single row per ID, right? That is, if the user checks per AM and AF (as in your image), there should only be one row, correct?

Comment: @langtang Correct, there needs to be one line per ID regardless of what is toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change to your `output$table1`. Basically, I check if `input$checkbox` has been given more than one choice; if so, change EventTypes to a constant so that there is only one row

```
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    
    res <- df() %>%
      mutate(EventTypes = gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", Event)) %>%
      filter(EventTypes %in% input$checkbox)

    if(length(input$checkbox)>1) {
      res <- mutate(res,EventTypes =paste0(input$checkbox,collapse="/"))
    }
    
    res %>% group_by(ID) %>%
      add_column(variable = "Thing") %>%
      mutate(times = 1:n(),
             tot_times = max(times)) %>%
      unite(both, variable, times) %>%
      spread(both, Event) %>%
      arrange(desc(tot_times))
  })
```